# emberjs model gets lost in controller

Tags: ember.js

Ember does great adding in the defaults for you.  But what happens when you have to override the default controller?

Consider the following example:
[data passes, then it does not](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qevixavufu/2/edit?html,js,output)

As you can see in the example, if you click 'account' you are presented with two sets addresses, 2 that pass the address value, and 2 that do not.

I guess I"m having trouble figuring out how to get the model data from the route for AccountEdit and pass it into the controller so it will show up in the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller generated for you is an ObjectController, not a regular Controller. The difference is that a property of the model on an ObjectController is accessible directly, i.e. an ObjectController proxies its model.

Either make AccountEditController an instance of ObjectController or in your account/edit template, or replace value=listing-address with value=model.listing-address.

Edit: Working JsBin without using ObjectController: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/mezeculiha/1/

Comment: I think that because of this confusion, the ObjectController will be deprecated.

Comment: Correct yes, would love to try and get a working example to fix this issue since the ObjectController will be deprecated.

Comment: I see it was simple as {{listing-address}} in one form and {{model.listing-address}} in the other for it to work, but lets say I'm using the same form to add and edit... we now have two different vars instead of just one.  It would be nice to always use:  {{listing-address}} without having to add model. in front of it.

Comment: You would have to explicitly make AccountEditController an ObjectController.

Answer (score 1):

`Ember.Controller` is just a base class provide base interfaces like actions, mixins and message passing etc.

But when you want to work with data then you have two choices -

`ObjectController` is used when you have only single instance of Model attached to your controller. Like 1 user , 1 post etc

> As @Gaurav has already pointed out if you just change you controller to
>   `ObjectController` then it will work. Why because it will tell your controller to look for model with one instance of data in it.

There also exists `ArrayController` which is used when you have array of records to iterate over. Like 10 comments etc.

> One more point worth noting when overriding the `setupController`
>   always call `this._super(controller,model)` at first line. Ember
>   use this method internally for binding data and other router setups.

There is always more to find out [here](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/controllers/representing-multiple-models-with-arraycontroller/).

Comment: ahhh ok.... very simple:    http://emberjs.jsbin.com/sobanuqonu/2/edit?html,js,output   App.AccountEditController = Ember.Controller.extend({});  to App.AccountEditController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({});

Comment: @Matt yes its simple :)